# Function symbols in many sorted logic

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Consider the following [definition](https://www.react.uni-saarland.de/teaching/decision-procedures-verification-06/ch01.pdf)

> We fix an enumerable set **Fun** of `function symbols`. Each function
>   symbol has associated to it an arity of the form $σ1 \times \cdots
>  \times σn \rightarrow σ$, where $n \ge 1$ and $σ1,\cdots , σn, σ$ are
>   sorts. We denote with $Fun_{\{σ1 \times \cdots  \times σn  \rightarrow  σ\}}$ the set of function symbols of arity $σ1 \times \cdots \times σn \rightarrow σ$. We assume that $Fun_{\{σ1 \times \cdots \times σn  \rightarrow σ\}}$ is enumerable, for all sorts $σ1, . . . , σn, σ$.

Arity in general refers to the number of arguments a function takes. Is the arity in the definition refers same?

Let $f$ is a function symbol, then is my interpretation true that the domain of $f$ is $σ1 \times \cdots \times σn$ and the 
range of $f$ is $σ$? If not then what are $σi'$s?

Comment: The author of your notes is abusing the term "arity". It should read "signature" or "type".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case *arity* is not "only" the number of argument places.

The funcion $f$ has $n$ argument places but each argument place $i$ must be "filled" with a term of sort $\sigma_i$.

Consider e.g a binary function $f$ whose arguments are the first one a *natural* number and the second one a *real* and whose value is a *complex* :

> $f : \mathbb N \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$.

Comment: "arity" is the wrong term to use here, so please don't encourage its use in this context. It should be "signature" or "type".